# Is it harmful to prune summer bearing raspberries in early autumn?

Tags: pruning, raspberries

I planted raspberry canes last autumn which have grown well and produced a good crop this year. Some of the canes have grown to 7 or 8 feet and are dangling over the fence into a neighbour's garden.

Can these be safely cut back at this time of year?  (early autumn, UK)

Comment: Related: [Pruning raspberries and boysenberries in early summer](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/799/pruning-raspberries-boysenberries-in-early-summer), [How do I maintain a Raspberry plant?](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/1621/394)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I live in Manchester, your neck of the woods, and have summer-bearing raspberry canes. I usually prune out the *fruited* canes to ground level in late summer/ early autumn, and the new canes always produce a good crop the following year; in fact, autumn pruning is recommended by the Royal Horticultural Society - see [How do I maintain a Raspberry plant?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/1621/136) Pruning out those long fruited canes now is not likely to cause the plants any harm at all.

Comment: Thanks, when you & the rhs say "fruited canes" do you mean the whole plant back to ground level or is there a bit I should be leaving alone?

Comment: @Twisted: Glad this helps. *Only" the canes that have produced fruit this year should be pruned out; the new (young) ones that have not borne fruit should be retained, as these are the ones that will fruit next summer.